# Android: Change parent layout of a button with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am writing my first android application using Eclipse. The screen of my application shows a 2x4 table of buttons (made using 4 linear layouts) and I have a method which shuffles the buttons by removing them from one linear layout and adding them to another. I have used android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in my xml but that just caused some of the buttons to blank-out before reappearing in their new spots. Is there any way to get a smooth transition? Thanks.

My xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnorange"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnyellow"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnblue"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btngreen"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnpink" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btncyan"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnred"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnviolet"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


</TableLayout>
```

My Activity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button redo;

TableLayout t1;

LinearLayout l1;
LinearLayout l2;
LinearLayout l3;
LinearLayout l4;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    l1= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    l2= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll2);
    l3= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll3);
    l4= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll4);

    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    b7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    b8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);


    ....

}


public void shuffle(){

    l1.removeAllViews();
    l2.removeAllViews();
    l3.removeAllViews();
    l4.removeAllViews();

    ArrayList<Button> a=new ArrayList<Button>(8);
    a.add(b1);
    a.add(b2);
    a.add(b3);
    a.add(b4);
    a.add(b5);
    a.add(b6);
    a.add(b7);
    a.add(b8);

    l1.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*8)));
    l1.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*7)));
    l2.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*6)));
    l2.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*5)));
    l3.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*4)));
    l3.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*3)));
    l4.addView(a.remove((int)(Math.random()*2)));
    l4.addView(a.remove(0));


}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: for smooth animation you need to use animatorset, translateAnimation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create "anim" folder in res directory
2. Create xml file named push_left.xml
3. Copy following code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shareInterpolator="false" >

       <translate
           android:duration="700"
           android:fromXDelta="0%"
           android:fromYDelta="0%"
           android:toXDelta="-100%"
           android:toYDelta="0%" />

   </set>
   ```
4. Instead of calling removeAllViews() method

   ```
   Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left);
   animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   });
   ```